# Any way to limit plugin rigths and resources?

Tags: c#, .net, plugins, architecture

We are developing and enterprise application with plugin-based architecture. Every plugin implements a contract that has a bunch of methods. All of those plugins are used in runtime by our core system and have their methods called permanantly. All of those calls must be async and in no way blocking.

We also give the ability for 3rd party developers to develop thier plugins. The problem is that this developers might implement some methods, which will not be async (by mistake or not). The worst case scenario is that this method will contain infinite loop.

We can put the call into separate thread, but after a couple of calls, those loops will take all the CPU time and could hung the system entirely.

Is there a way to ensure that those calls are not blocking and not resource critical?
P.S. We can drop any plugin at runtime if it's suspicious.